# How can I use askopenfile to get a valid filename

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program with Tkinter and tkFileDialog that opens a file for reading and then packs it into a text widget but, whenever I run this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile
import time
m = Tk()

def filefind():
   file = askopenfile()
   f = open(str(file), "r+")
   x = f.read()
   t = Text(m)
   t.insert(INSERT, x)
   t.pack()


b = Button(m, text='File Picker', command=filefind)
b.pack()
m.mainloop()
```

I get this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\super\PycharmProjects\untitled1\File Picker.py", line in    filefind
f = open(str(file), "r+")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r+') or filename: "<open file u'C:/Users/super/PycharmProjects/untitled1/util.h', mode 'r' at 0x00000000026E0390>"
```

Comment: I Accidentally Misspelled Get My Bad

Comment: Btw, english words usually start with a lowercase letter if not at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: It seems like `askopenfile()` already returns a file-object, so you don't have to use `open()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue; `askopenfile()` is returning an object, not just the name.  If you print `file`, you will get `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/File/Path/To/File.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`.  You want the `name=` from the object.  To get that, all you need to do is replace `f = open(str(file), "r+")` with `f = open(file.name, "r+")`.

Here is how it will look in your code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile
import time
m = Tk()

def filefind():
    file = askopenfile()
    f = open(file.name, "r+")  # This will fix the issue.
    x = f.read()
    t = Text(m)
    t.insert(INSERT, x)
    t.pack()


b = Button(m, text='File Picker', command=filefind)
b.pack()
m.mainloop()
```

***Edit***

A cleaner way of doing this is by letting `askopenfile()` do the work of opening a file instead of 're-opening' it again with `open()`.  Here is the cleaner version:

```
file = askopenfile()
x = file.read()
```

Comment: Thank You So Much It Worked

Comment: Glad to help.  If you don't mind, please make this answer as 'correct' so others with the same problem can find it easier.

Comment: Why are you suggesting he reopen the file? It's already open so there's no need to open it again.

Comment: That is a good point, I didn't realize that.  I'll make an edit; thanks for the insight.